# Assign to variable in BashScript

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

This command gets all the users from the logs.  It works great

```
grep $srcIP $cFilename | grep "Username: " | awk -F"Username: " '{print $2}'| awk -F"," '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

so it would display

```
user1 user2 user3 user4 etc...
```

I assign it to a variable, so far so good

```
getUser=$(grep $srcIP $cFilename | grep "Username: " | awk -F"Username: " '{print $2}'| awk -F"," '{print $1}' | sort -u)
```

If I want to display the second user

```
echo $getUser | awk '{print $2}'
```

It would display 
user2

But if I assign that command to a variable

```
tmp=$($getUser | awk '{print $2}')
```

Now, I'm getting an error message 
**user2: command not found**

Would anyone know how to assign this command statement to a variable?

```
$getUser | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: Hint: `echo $getUser | awk '{print $2}'` that works is *different* than `$getUser | awk '{print $2}'` which is a part of the command that doesn't work. Additionally: [quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your issue.

```
tmp=$($getUser | awk '{print $2}')
```

Let's break this down. $(...) is going to execute the code inside.

What you have next is '$getUser' so that's going to output (in this case) 'User2'.

So when $(...) runs it's looking for a command named 'User2'. And that's when you hit the error 'User2: command not found'.

What you need to do is print out $getUser, add 'echo' in front, this way the '$(...)' will execute 'echo' and not try running a command named 'User2'.

```
tmp=$(echo $getUser | awk '{print $2}')
```